# Embedded CSS and XSLT within XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to generate a **single** XML file that provides both HTML DOM structuring (via embedded XSLT) and CSS formatting (via embedded CSS). While I've not yet managed to get this to work, I'm using pages such as http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html for reference and troubleshooting/testing.

When used independently, both the XSLT and CSS work fine. When used as embedded resources, I get nothing (useful).

sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="#customCSS" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST style
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
  <xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
                  version="1.0"
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="style" />
    <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />

    <xsl:template match="data">
      <html>
        <body>
          <div id="Title">Data File Title</div>
          <div id="Descr">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>

  <style id="customCSS">
    #Title {
      font-size: large;
      color: #5B9BD5;
    }
    #customCSS { display: none }
    </style>
  <data Description="Sample Data Description Here">
    <moredata location="here" />
  </data>
</doc>
```

When I view the file, all I see is:

```
Data File Title
```

followed by all of the contents of `<style id="customCSS">`.

CSS: I do not get any of the default formatting I'd expect, like standard `<div>` behavior, nor do I get any of the custom CSS.

XSLT: the `value-of` @Description does not appear either

help?

Thanks in advance :)

---

edits:

- added reference to W3C for some reference about using embedded stylesheets.
- some more reading suggests that I may need to look into XSL-FO (http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_intro.asp), though I'm not sure it'll give me the options I'm looking for, that HTML can provide.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this approach is not going to work. `#stylesheet` is not a URL to the `xsl:stylesheet` element of that XML document so the browser has no idea what to do with it. Likewise for `#stylesheet`. The result you are getting is simply the value of all the text nodes in your document. No XSLT or CSS processing is being applied.

Comment: Use of embedded stylesheets are defined by w3c at: http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html

Comment: From that page: **As of February 2006, there are still technical problems with this and no formal specification exists.** None of the embedded stylesheet examples provided on that page work in IE, FF, or Chrome.

Comment: @Scott XSLT is for running on the server (or, maybe in a separate JS XSLT engine). Integrated native client side support is so inconsistent that you're wasting your time trying.